# Save the differences between two dates in list flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to store the dates between two dates in list for example if the
start date = 3/4/2021 and the end date = 7/4/2021
then the list items are [3/4/2021,4/4/2021,5/4/2021,6/4/2021,7/4/2021]

```
 DateTime medStartDate =
doc[index]['medicationStartDate'].toDate();
DateTime medEndDate = doc[index]['medicationEndDate'].toDate();
final difference = medEndDate.difference(medStartDate).inDays;
```

but how to save the dates ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over a range like this:

```
void main() {
  final startDate = DateTime.now();
  final endDate = startDate.add(Duration(days: 5));
  final interval = calculateInterval(startDate, endDate);
  print(interval);
}

List<DateTime> calculateInterval(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {
  List<DateTime> days = [];
  for (int i = 0; i <= endDate.difference(startDate).inDays; i++) {
    days.add(startDate.add(Duration(days: i)));
  }
  return days;
}
```

And the result:

```
[2021-04-07 16:27:15.480, 2021-04-08 16:27:15.480, 2021-04-09 16:27:15.480, 2021-04-10 16:27:15.480, 2021-04-11 16:27:15.480, 2021-04-12 16:27:15.480]
```